# Twilio - Modifying a call in progress results in error

Tags: twilio

I am getting an error (call resource not found) when I try to modify a live Twilio call that is in progress. I have followed the Twilio documentation but no luck. Here is my code to modify the Twiml URL for the live call. My call is being processed in AU1 region. Code is running as a serverless function:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  // Here's an example of setting up some TWiML to respond to with this function
    //let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  
  const client = context.getTwilioClient({
        accountSid: 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        edge: 'sydney',
        region: 'au1'
    });

  //Try to switch the in progress call to another URL
  client.calls(event.callSID)
      .update({method: "POST",url: "https://myservice-20xxx.twil.io/new-url"})
      .then(call => console.log('URL switching worked'))
      .catch(err => console.log('URL switching did not work', err));

  // This callback is what is returned in response to this function being invoked.
  // It's really important! E.g. you might respond with TWiML here for a voice or SMS response.
  // Or you might return JSON data to a studio flow. Don't forget it!
  return callback(null, true);
};
```

I am getting the following error when this code gets executed:

```
URL switching did not work [RestException [Error]: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcc3/Calls/CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json was not found] { status: 404, code: 20404, moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404', detail: undefined }
```

I checked the call logs and the specific call Sid is definitely present. Any help to point me in the right direction would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the call you are modifying exist in the same account or subaccount as the function?

Comment: Hi there, yes the call is processed within a sub-account and the function also exists within the same sub-account. The only difference is that the function code is executed in US region (as serverless functions are not available in AU region). I am however passing the edge and. region parameters when creating my twilio client.

Comment: Try creating the client without passing the region parameters and SID. Try using: const client = context.getTwilioClient();

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no luck.

Comment: Is the call that you are trying to modify "in-progress"? Only "in-progress" calls can be modified.

Answer (score -2):

Twilio Developer advocate here.

I have asked around to find you a quick response but in the meantime here is some knowledge I have gathered.

Please note you are hard coding the Account number to a string with the value of  'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'.

The error you're encountering, "The requested resource... was not found," usually indicates that Twilio couldn't locate the specified resource in the specified region. There might be a few issues in your code that you should review:

**Edge and Region Configuration:** Ensure that you've correctly set the edge and region when creating your Twilio client. In your code, you've set edge to 'sydney' and region to 'au1'. Make sure you've chosen the correct values for your use case. Double-check that you are using the right accountSid as well.

**Provisioning:** Make sure that the call SID you're trying to update actually exists and is active. Verify that you are passing the correct event.callSID and that it corresponds to a live call.

**URL Format:** Ensure that the URL you're trying to switch to is accessible and correctly formatted. It should be a publicly accessible URL that returns valid TwiML. You can test the URL in a web browser to make sure it is accessible.

**Method:** The method you're using, "POST," is correct for updating a call's URL. However, be sure that your serverless function is capable of handling incoming HTTP POST requests.

**Permissions:** Check that the Twilio account associated with your accountSid has the necessary permissions to modify live calls. Ensure that there are no restrictions or permission issues on your Twilio account.

I know this might seem like common sense but I am hoping it provides you with some clarity.

Comment: THanks for responding. I can confirm that the account SID is correct and also the call SID is valid since I get it passed from the live call and I also check that it existing in call logs after the call. THe edge and region values are also correct.  The switching URL is also tested as I can switch to it directly and it works. If you see the error, it seems to not find the Call record.

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: "[Engagment](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Engagment) Manager"? What? How can we take that seriously?